# Sass nesting doesn't compile properly

Tags: css, sass

I't would be really nice if someone could explain why this sass

```
@media screen and (max-width: 991px)

    .product-stats
        display: block

    .product-stats-block
        display: block
        &:last-child
            display: none
```

gets compiled as

```
@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    .product-stats {display: block}
    .product-stats .product-stats-block {display: block}
    .product-stats .product-stats-block:last-child {display: none}
```

(notice how every next selector, after a **.product-stats** gets nested inside it, yet there's no padding for next selectors in sass syntax).

**UPD**

I've moved .product-stats to the bottom of media query, now it throws an error @ cmd -

```
Error: Invalid CSS after "...lay: block; } }": expected 1 selector or at-
rule, was "{"on line 59 of src/sass/_media.sass
>>              display: block; } } {
-----------------------^
```

Error appears for any property applied to .product-stats.

Comment: Why do you need to have an empty `.product-stats` class. Remove it if you don't want any associated styling

Comment: I've added the properties back. At first i've removed them before posting the question, because it didn't affect compilation nesting. P.s. check the upd.

Comment: It seems like a syntax problem. We need to see much more of your code.